# how to specify VM options if i want to see output on cmd

Tags: jvm

I am trying out java **`GarbageCollector`** and VM options.

I wanted to know if i can try out these options 
on command line (windows **`cmd`**) with few sample programs and check the output

**Example:**

```
java <java filenam> -verbose:gc --XX:+PrintGCDetails
```

is this valid ?
How to check this?

Comment: Wait, why don't you just run it and see what happens?

Comment: Yeah, i tried executing it before posting here; but it just gives the program output and prints nothing on cmd

Comment: @shaileshp well, the JVM option -verbose:gc and -XX:+PrintGCDetails are to be added before <java filename>, otherwise they would be considered as arguments to your Java application, not to JVM.

Comment: Thanks much Ashutosh, yes i can see the output.